# Augmented Reality without displaying camera feed

Tags: unity-game-engine, computer-vision, augmented-reality, wikitude, artoolkit

I'm trying to decide which AR tool to use for my Unity3d project.
The candidates are ARToolkit and Wikitude.
What I'm also looking for is *turning off the camera feed*, but still showing a virtual object that rotates and shrinks/grows in size depending on a marker's position or rotation.

For example, If I want to display a red 3d cube above a marker, I'd like to display just the cube on a black background and not display anything else. Do any of AR tools support this feature? It's okay if it's not ARToolkit or Wikitude.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARToolkit has that functionality, you just need to check the box named "See-through display" on the ARCamera script.

When using a see-through display, black is considered transparent because it is not rendered. I guess you want it for a similar reason.

For more info about that, including how to calibrate a see-through display, you can check the official documentation: [Using an Optical See-Through Display](https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=8_Advanced_Topics:config_optical_see-through)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Wikitude Plugin, you can also achieve this by adding the following script to the camera that does the rendering.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

public class CustomCameraRenderer : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture2D textureToRender;

    void Start () {
        var buffer = new CommandBuffer();

        buffer.Blit(textureToRender, BuiltinRenderTextureType.CameraTarget);
        var camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        CameraEvent eventForBlit;

        if (camera.actualRenderingPath == RenderingPath.Forward) {
            eventForBlit = CameraEvent.BeforeForwardOpaque;
        } else {
            eventForBlit = CameraEvent.BeforeGBuffer;
        }
        camera.AddCommandBuffer(eventForBlit, buffer);
    }
}
```

Then just add the texture you want as background in the inspector of this script.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Shalafi's comment...if you dig into the ARcontroller script on line 1222 and find

> clearCamera.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.SolidColor;

If SolidColor is changed to Skybox, the black then becomes a camera view into unity.